# Problem when linking react-native-vector-icons

Tags: react-native

I just started a new react-native project from zero, added react-native-vector-icons, but when i try to link it, I get the following, I have no idea why this is happening, I didn't change anything, it's a clen project.

```
error Something went wrong while linking. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile 'PROJECTFOLDER/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/AntDesign.ttf' -> 'D:\Codes\ReactNative\KosTimer\android\app\src\main\assets\fonts\AntDesign.ttf'
Please file an issue here: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cli/issues
error ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile 'PROJECTFOLDER/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/AntDesign.ttf' -> 'D:\Codes\ReactNative\KosTimer\android\app\src\main\assets\fonts\AntDesign.ttf'
```

Because of this error, all my icons appear with a X inside a square

*PROJECTFOLDER is the place where is my project

Comment: `react-native: 0.59.0` was just released 10 hours ago. There are bound to be teething issues you could always create a project with the previous version using `react-native init MyAwesomeApp --version react-native@0.58.6` and see if that works.

Comment: It works, but I want with 0.59, I'm upgrading so  I can use hooks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is caused by a missing `assets/fonts` folder inside the `android` project.

To solve the issue create an assets folder in your project.

[image]

Then inside that folder create a folder called `fonts`.

This is what should have:

```
<project root>/android/app/src/main/assets/fonts
```

---

If you want to do with one command, you can open a terminal at your project root and type:

For mac:

```
mkdir -p ./android/app/src/main/assets/fonts
```

For windows:

```
mkdir ./android/app/src/main/assets/fonts
```

Then you should be able to link the dependency as normal.

Comment: i think you can do it with `mkdir ./android/app/src/main/assets/fonts` notice no **-p**. Let me know if that works. Worse case you can just navigate to the `main` directory and create the `assets` folder and then inside that the `fonts` folder

Comment: I am not sure why, but I suppose it could be that the linking command just copies the contents and doesn't create the folder if it doesn't exist.